# Ground sensors in Ocean's Eleven vault

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-eleven

In the Bellagio vault, there were ground sensors, shown as green lasers. It's because of them that Glenn needs to jump around without being on the ground. However, the gang explodes the vault doors and it's as if the sensors just vanished.

Is this a plot hole? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

As Yen is setting the charges on the vault door, Basher walks into HQ asking for a status update, and Livingston replys 'pins and floor sensors now', indicating that the charges are positioned to take out the door pins and floor sensors all at once.

Comment: Very nice, incorporating in-universe explanation and deducing what happened. +1

Answer (score 4):

This surely is one of the mistakes that the movie makers made. There is actually no way that the explosion at the door could have disabled the power supply (or even opened the door - as an engineer this bothers me every time I watch the movie). By the way, the reason the Chinese guy jumps is motion detectors, not the ground sensors. One could argue that the ground sensors only monitor the ground and not the inside of the vault (but why then are the motion sensors suddenly out of order when the door opens??) or you could argue that the ground sensors are for long term monitoring instead of being an alarm system.

But for an actual answer, its an mistake. Other mistakes are that there is no way the bags with the hooker flyers could have made their way into the vault or that Mr. Walsh is simultaneously watching the cameras with Liman Zerga and showing Frank the exit.

A con this complex is obviously too complex even to IMAGINE a way to do it

Comment: Weren't the hooker flier bags brought in by the SWAT team?

Comment: No, there is one scene where you can see them roping down the elevator without the bags. They could have thrown them down the shaft but then they would have burst probably and, on top, why would a swat team bring two massive bags each

Comment: @JoschKraus: why would SWAT carry two massive bags each when leaving? It makes more sense to have SWAT appear with the bags in the beginning; as opposed to them visibly returning with full(er) hands after exiting the vault. If SWAT also carried the bags in, it makes sense to assume it is their equipment. Not so if they never arrived with bags in the first place.

Comment: Yes I thought about that and you are right, we must assume just one more not logical thing in the movie

Answer (score 2):

After explosion security of vault was compromised including ground sensors as they are part of vault and connected to doors. So ground sensors system was also damaged, simply like if you take fuse out of your house, nothing would work.
This is my theory, it might have been good if they had short explanation of this in movie.